# Volume Under a Plane

Tags: integration, volume

Find the volume under $z = 3x$ and about he $1$st quadrant area in the $xy$ plane bounded by

$$
x = 0,\quad y = 0,\quad x = 4,
\quad x^{2} + y^{2}=25,
$$

$$\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{25-x^{2}}3x\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y = 98.$$

Not sure if this is correct. I was confused if this took the volume of the area b/w $$4<x<5 $$ and $$0<y<\sqrt{25-x^{2}}$$ as well, so a second integral would be needed to remove this portion of volume.

I appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: Dont we need also $z=0$ plane to bound it from below?

Answer (score 0):

$$Volume= \int_{0}^4 \int_{0}^{\sqrt{25-x^2}} 3x \ dy \ dx $$

Answer (score 0):

I would say, in the second integration substitute $x = 5\sin t, \ dx = 5\cos t\,dt$

$\displaystyle V=3\int_{0}^{4} \int_{0}^{\color{red}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}} x \,dy\, dx=\cdots =3\int_{0}^{4} x\sqrt{25-x^2}\,dx=3\cdot 125\int_{0}^{\arccos \frac{3}{5}}\sin t \cos^2 t \,dt=\\=-125 \cdot [\cos^3 t]_0^{\arccos \frac{3}{5}}=\cdots = 98$